# C : Why startingTime is larger than endingTime with gettimeofday()?

Tags: c, gettimeofday

I'd like to measure the computing time with while loop.

I'm programming with  C99 version.

My code is below:

```
struct timeval startingTime,endingTime;
gettimeofday(&startingTime, NULL);
while(read(fd,&student,206) != 0){
    printf("%s\n",student);
}
gettimeofday(&endingTime, NULL);
long elapsed = endingTime.tv_usec-startingTime.tv_usec;
printf("Computing Time : %ld\n",elapsed);
printf("ending : %d , starting %d",endingTime.tv_usec,startingTime.tv_usec);
```

Then the result is below :

> Computing Time : -76716
>
> ending : 334481 , starting 411197

As you see, starting is bigger than ending...

I can not totally understand what I'm missing...

Is there anyone who knows this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`struct timeval` has actually two members, a `tv_sec` member and a `tv_usec` member.  `tv_usec` is the number of usec pass that `tv_sec` value, which is in seconds (as the name implies).

So you have to check the `tv_sec` difference first, and than calculate the `tv_usec` difference (taking into account wraparound).

What you are doing currently is similar to checking only the minutes differences when the duration was a couple of hours.  The ending minutes might be greater then starting minutes, since the hour can have increased as well.

Comment: What is this sentence meaning "tv_usec is the number of usec pass that tv_sec value"?

Comment: You can also compute a microsecond-resolution timestamp as `(long long)foo.tv_sec * 1000000 + `(long long)foo.tv_usec`. (This makes some assumptions about how `time_t` values are represented, but it should be ok on most current systems.)

Comment: @LKM tv_usec is the number of microsecond after the tv_sec second value, in the same sense that for 10:30, 30 is the number of minutes after that 10 hours value.  They are not the representation of the same value using different units.  Does this clarify the difference?

Comment: @LaurentParenteau Yes, it does... Thank you for help!